# Create foreground/background color pair presets to cycle through

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am doing some work with pictures where I am going to doodle in colored cloud effects into some existing nebula to try and give a little more definition to the features I am seeing. For this I wanted to know if I can make a set of foreground/background pairs I can cycle through since I need 10-15 pairs of colors that I'll probably have to cycle between. I have moderate familiarity with photoshop but still am lacking full familiarity with the UI. Thanks.

Comment: The best/least complicated option that comes to mind is making an Action for each set of colors, which you can then activate with the assigned shortcut keys. --- You could always make a script that toggles between swatches in sets of two, but I would just make swatches in the Swatches panel And pick them from there. Doesn't take too long. You can pick two colors, by first clicking the foreground color swatch and then with Cmd pressed, the background swatch.

Comment: was there an easy way of just making a list of colors that i could just rapidly select out of for foreground/background?

Comment: Only the three methods that I mentioned. Nothing else comes to mind. I mean I guess the closest to what you want would be an extension (which is pretty much script(s) with a panel gui), but you'd pretty much have to make that yourself, as I doubt something this specific exists as a script or as an extension.

Comment: The best option for you might be just making swatches and picking them with and without cmd as I mentioned earlier. Because photoshop doesn't have groups for swatches, you might wanna do something like: add white swatch between every set of 2 swatches, so it's easier to differentiate. The only difference to what you want is that you need two mouse clicks instead of one.